# dynamically adjusting the size of multiple DIVs

Tags: javascript, html

I am displaying the json response on html page using javascript.
Response may contain multiple results and one link corresponding to each result. I am displaying this dynamically.

Code for this is :

```
var response=eval('(' + request.responseText + ')');

        for(i=0;i<response.items.length;i++)
        {

            var innerDivElement=document.createElement('div');
            divElement.appendChild(innerDivElement);
            innerDivElement.setAttribute("id", response.items[i].link);
            innerDivElement.setAttribute("title","link_attr");
            innerDivElement.setAttribute("class","links");
            innerDivElement.innerHTML=response.items[i].link;
        }
```

Here all the DIVs are having same height and width. I want to adjust the size of DIV depending on the size of its innerHTML. How this can be done?

Comment: You should never use `eval`: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/

Comment: Can you explain how the size of the `innerHTML` should affect the size of the `div` (height and/or width)..?

Comment: Divs by nature sized based on their content. If yours are fixed sized than it is because your css rules force them. Change your css

Comment: if the innerHTML contains "hello" word then the size of div should only be to accomodate "hello" word

Comment: css for div is:   div.links{
font-size:14pt;
color: blue;
}

Comment: Assuming that '.links' is the class of the div with the problem, try and set the divs min-height and max-height. Otherwise you might have the wrong class selected?

Comment: I'm confused. It sounds like all you're asking for is to add `height: auto` to your class, which does not involve any javascript. Surely, I must have misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should really try to use JavaScript Frameworks like jQuery. The eval() function, for example, is not very safe. But anyway:

If you set a min-height and min-width to a low value in the CSS for the DIV that holds the inner elements, it will stretch automatically when needed.

The JS way:

```
divElement.setAttribute("class", "innerElementHolder");
```

Or if you are retrieving this divElement from a HTML page, just add:

```
class="innerElementHolder"
```

to the DIV that holds all elements you create in you JS.

The innerElementHolder CSS should be something like:

```
.innerElementHolder {
    min-height: 10px;
    min-width: 10px;
}
```